# Getting many errors with Python Pymem

Tags: python-3.x

I am making hacks for CSGO using Pymem(Bot only servers, don't worry) but keep getting errors. I decided to use threading because my functions have infinite while loops. But I keep getting the following errors:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gjohn\PycharmProjects\csgoGlow\venv\lib\site-packages\pymem\__init__.py", line 484, in read_int
    value = pymem.memory.read_int(self.process_handle, address)
  File "C:\Users\gjohn\PycharmProjects\csgoGlow\venv\lib\site-packages\pymem\memory.py", line 271, in read_int
    bytes = read_bytes(handle, address, struct.calcsize('i'))
  File "C:\Users\gjohn\PycharmProjects\csgoGlow\venv\lib\site-packages\pymem\memory.py", line 105, in read_bytes
    raise pymem.exception.WinAPIError(error_code)
pymem.exception.WinAPIError: Windows api error, error_code: 998

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/gjohn/PycharmProjects/csgoGlow/main.py", line 34, in glow
    entity_team_id = pm.read_int(entity + m_iTeamNum)
  File "C:\Users\gjohn\PycharmProjects\csgoGlow\venv\lib\site-packages\pymem\__init__.py", line 486, in read_int
    raise pymem.exception.MemoryReadError(address, struct.calcsize('i'), e.error_code)
pymem.exception.MemoryReadError: Could not read memory at: -1899196620, length: 4 - GetLastError: 998
```

and I'm not sure why. Here is my code:

```
import keyboard
import pymem
import pymem.process
import time
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
import threading

dwEntityList = (0x4DA2F44)
dwGlowObjectManager = (0x52EB540)
m_iGlowIndex = (0xA438)
dwForceAttack = (0x31D44D4)
dwForceJump = (0x524CEA4)
dwLocalPlayer = (0xD8B2BC)
m_fFlags = (0x104)
m_iCrosshairId = (0xB3E4)
m_iTeamNum = (0xF4)
m_flFlashMaxAlpha = (0xA41C)

trigger_key = "shift"


def glow():
   print("Diamond has launched.")
   pm = pymem.Pymem("csgo.exe")
   client = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "client.dll").lpBaseOfDll

   while True:
       glow_manager = pm.read_int(client + dwGlowObjectManager)

       for i in range(1, 32):  # Entities 1-32 are reserved for players.
           entity = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + i * 0x10)

           if entity:
               entity_team_id = pm.read_int(entity + m_iTeamNum)
               entity_glow = pm.read_int(entity + m_iGlowIndex)

               if entity_team_id == 2:  # Terrorist
                   pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x4, float(1))   # R
                   pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x8, float(1))   # G
                   pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0xC, float(0))   # B
                   pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x10, float(1))  # Alpha
                   pm.write_int(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x24, 1)           # Enable glow

               elif entity_team_id == 3:  # Counter-terrorist
                   pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x4, float(0))   # R
                   pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x8, float(0))   # G
                   pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0xC, float(1))   # B
                   pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x10, float(1))  # Alpha
                   pm.write_int(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x24, 1)           # Enable glow
def triggerBot():
   print("Sapphire has launched.")
   pm = pymem.Pymem("csgo.exe")
   client = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "client.dll").lpBaseOfDll

   while True:
       if not keyboard.is_pressed(trigger_key):
           time.sleep(0.1)

       if not GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()) == "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive":
           continue

       if keyboard.is_pressed(trigger_key):
           player = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
           entity_id = pm.read_int(player + m_iCrosshairId)
           entity = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + (entity_id - 1) * 0x10)

           entity_team = pm.read_int(entity + m_iTeamNum)
           player_team = pm.read_int(player + m_iTeamNum)

           if entity_id > 0 and entity_id <= 64 and player_team != entity_team:
               pm.write_int(client + dwForceAttack, 6)

           time.sleep(0.006)

def speed():
   print("Ruby has launched.")
   pm = pymem.Pymem("csgo.exe")
   client = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "client.dll").lpBaseOfDll

   while True:
       if not GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()) == "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive":
           continue

       if keyboard.is_pressed("space"):
           force_jump = client + dwForceJump
           player = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
           if player:
               on_ground = pm.read_int(player + m_fFlags)
               if on_ground and on_ground == 257:
                   pm.write_int(force_jump, 5)
                   time.sleep(0.08)
                   pm.write_int(force_jump, 4)

       time.sleep(0.002)

def flash():
   print("Emerald has launched.")
   pm = pymem.Pymem("csgo.exe")
   client = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "client.dll").lpBaseOfDll

   while True:
       player = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
       if player:
           flash_value = player + m_flFlashMaxAlpha
           if flash_value:
               pm.write_float(flash_value, float(0))
       time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   thread1 = threading.Thread(target=speed)
   thread2 = threading.Thread(target=glow)
   thread3 = threading.Thread(target=triggerBot)
   thread4 = threading.Thread(target=flash)

   thread1.start()
   thread2.start()
   thread3.start()
   thread4.start()

   thread1.join()
   thread2.join()
   thread3.join()
   thread4.join()
```

I tried everything, and it kinda worked for a bit, until I added the 4th function. This doesn't make sense, since the errors aren't for that thread, and when I comment that thread out, glow still returns this error.

Answer (score 1):

Im getting this error to, in fact i tried several different variants of my code, basically one to write to the pointer and other to read the point and im also getting this win api errors, Error 299 and 998.

I believe this is something to do with pymem itself, you can try to write it in c++, i believe thats more suited for reading and writing memory, alternatively you can also try ReadWriteMemory another python module, but i doubt you will have any luck with that to, its been discontinued and i myself tried it and it doesnt seem able to read the addresses without getting some Overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting error code 998, which is ERROR_NOACCESS, meaning that you are trying to access an invalid memory location.

this is probably because the address you're trying to read hasn't loaded, so I would try running some checks first before changing it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--500-999- <- error code documentation